# How do I load sub nodes for a node which is clicked asynchronously

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jstree

Hi I am using jstree plugin for my project  for showing categories/subcategories in treeview style. 
I want to load sub nodes for a node, which is selected/clicked.
I do not want to load the full tree at once.

I have seperate mysql table for 
1)main category(root nodes)
2)subcategory_level1 
3)subcategory_level2 
4)subcategory_level3

will it be possible like this
1) User clicks on node, and gets id (worked for me)
2)using ajax i send the id to a php file and get the sub level nodes for the passed id of node(i was not able to do this.Please guide here)
show the sublevel nodes for the selected nodes.

these are links to jstree plugin example  that i found.
[link1](http://luban.danse.us/jazzclub/javascripts/jquery/jsTree/reference/_examples/1_datasources.html)
[link2](http://www.jstree.com/demo)

Comment: use jQuery.load for this.http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I didnt get, can  you please give more details. there is "PHP & mySQL demo + event order" at this page http://www.jstree.com/demo. i want my tree to work like that

Comment: What part of flow doesn't work for you?

Comment: I wanted to load(expand/show) subnodes of the node, which is selected.I am not able to get ; how to do that.                     <br/>I was able to load the tree again with subnodes of selected node; on click of the node.